# Unit Testing in PHPUnit - Handling Multiple Conditions

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, logical-operators

I want to write a test using PHPUnit which includes a check to make sure that a value is either a `string` *or* `NULL`.

AFAIK, I can write such a test like so:

```
if (is_string($value) || is_null($value)) { 
    $result = TRUE; 
} else { 
    $result = FALSE; 
} 

$this->assertTrue($result);
```

However, I've seen that PHPUnit has a `logicalOr()` method, which I don't know if I should be using to make a more 'native' test? And if I should be using it, I can't figure out how to do so...

Comment: Can't you write `$result = is_string($value) || is_null($value)`?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Yes, it could be written more efficiently. That's not really the question though - it's whether I should be doing that bit of the test in PHP or if I can/should use PHPUnits `logicalOr()` method some how.

Comment: I want to recommend you to simulate both situations and make seperate assertions for them.
If you get caught in situations like this, consider it a heads-up that your unit tests are probably not effective.

Answer (score 5):

Using phpunit v5.5 it (also) works this way:

```
if (is_string($value) || is_null($value)) { 
    $result = TRUE; 
} else { 
    $result = FALSE; 
} 

$this->assertThat($value, $this->logicalOr(
    $this->isType('string'),
    $this->isNull()
));
```

Answer (score 1):

`logicalOr` returns an object that is used to build a condition that can be passed to `assertThat`. I can't check the syntax on my phone, but it should look something like this:

```
self::assertThat(self::logicalOr(self::stringValue(), self::nullValue()));
```

The method names are no doubt incorrect as I am used to Hamcrest, but I he structure is similar.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is the one which will give you the most usable output in the event of a problem. In this case, I don't think it matters too much which way you so it, as long as you know what went wrong. The following code will provide a meaningful error message:

```
$message = '$value should have been either a string or null, but was actually a '
           .gettype($value);
$this->asertTrue($valueIsEitherStringOrNull, $message);
```